# How do I log in to Android Messages for Web without my phone?

Tags: sms, webview

I recently discovered the Android Messages for Web service! My immediate thought was, awesome! If I forget my phone at home, I can still text when I'm at work. In an emergency, I could send a text message using a friend's computer.

However, when I logged in, I discovered that I needed to use my phone to log in by scanning a QR code on my computer screen. I'm afraid that this defeats the purpose for me.

(I'm aware that it has a "remember me on this computer" feature so it will work in some cases when I don't have my phone with me, as long as I've recently logged in on that computer with this option enabled. But this is not all computers at all times, so it defeats the "in case of emergency" situation.)

Is there any way to authenticate myself to Android Messages for Web without having my phone with me?

Comment: No. This appears to be Google's intended purpose.